# Where can functions appear in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Given a function `xyz()` in PostgreSQL, where and how can I actually use it?

Consider the function `current_database()` for example.
I can perform the following queries then:

```
SELECT current_database();
SELECT * FROM current_database();
```

And in this case both result in the output:

```
 current_database
------------------
 cassava
(1 row)
```

Are there any other places I can use this function?

**In particular:** how could I write the following, so that it works (because as it stands, it does not).

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE current_database() TO GROUP wheel WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: For the moment, let's leave PL/pgSQL out of the discussion.

Comment: The use of the function `current_database()` is just an example function; I'm more interested in the general concept. (But on the side, I would also like to be able to solve things like writing the last `GRANT ...` statement correctly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Huxton is right: wherever you can use an *expression* in an SQL statement, you should be able to use a function.

PostgreSQL has the [DO extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) however, which lets you run a procedural language without having to create a function. This makes building dynamic queries easy.

For the particular situation (omitting `WITH GRANT OPTION`):

```
DO $$
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON DATABASE ' || current_database() || ' TO GROUP wheel';
    END;
$$;
```

This effectively lets you use a function anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the GRANT ALL example in pure SQL because the syntax requires an identifier - not an expression returning an identifier.

Anywhere you can use an expression in an SQL statement you should be able to use a function.

Beyond that you will need to use plpgsql (or one of the other procedural languages) to dynamically build a query-string.

Comment: So basically, I would have to create a function? Let's say I have an sql script that I would like to load, with that expression. I want it to be database agnostic. What do I do then?

Comment: How were you planning to make a database agnostic sql script? Fame and fortune awaits if you can.

Comment: Haha, well, I just wanted it not to depend on how I named the database, because I wanted to apply the script on different servers, which have the same data, but might (for whatever reason) have the database named differently.

Comment: Simple parameter substitution is easy. Psql has \set variables or if you are feeding the scripts through a client language just use your preferred templating system.